# is it safe to open a psu (open the casing) after being unplugged for 6 months +

Tags: power-supply

as the title says, is it safe/ is there any chance of electrocution by opening a psu casing after being unplugged for a very long time. for the inspection of capacitors

Answer (score 2):

At said in the [following](http://www.labour.gov.hk/text_alternative/foreign/eng/isolation_eng.pdf) document in chapter 8:

> In
>   case
>   there is
>   other
>   stored
>   energy
>   source,
>   e.g.
>   standby
>   battery
>   banks 
>   or
>   capacitor
>   etc.,
>   fixed
>   in
>   the
>   electrical
>   installation,
>   or
>   the
>   capacitance 
>   of
>   the
>   circuit
>   is
>   large,
>   any
>   stored
>   energy
>   should
>   be
>   safely
>   isolated
>   or
>   discharged
>   first
>   before
>   carrying
>   out
>   work

You need to wear gloves to protect yourself from electrocution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't absolutely guarantee that capacitors will be discharged - it depends on the design of the PSU and the type of capacitors used, but it is highly unlikely that they will still retain any significant charge. Unless the PSU is a particularly specialised one - eg. very high voltage output I would have no concerns about opening most PSU's after that period!

Comment: As I think you are talking about the DELL PSU you asked about in question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199225/is-it-safe-to-test-a-pc-with-a-possiblly-burnt-psu I suspect that you have done more than damage just capacitors.